# create item for the list From Another Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

i created two workflows for the same list. The first workflow starts automatically when creating an item, and the second workflow starts when editing an item, so i want to create an item from the 2nd workflow.
Now when I update any item, the second workflow starts and creates a new item in the list. But The first workflow didn't work.

How can the first workflow start in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System Account is not allowed to start a workflow. When you create a new list item using a workflow, that new item is created by the System Account. So on any new item created by a workflow, "Start workflow on create" will not work. The workaround is to put "Create new item" inside an impersonation step in the second workflow. This will create the new item under the name of the person who publishes the workflow, and the first workflow will start on the newly created item.

I also like to create a new service account, in Central Admin, and publish the workflow from that account, rather than having items look like they were created by me when they were actually created by a workflow.

1. Place your cursor outside of any steps, then click Impersonation Step in the ribbon.
2. Insert action "Create list item"
3. Click on "Current List" to specific field values for the new item.

[image]

Comment: i don't Know how to put this action inside an impersonation step !!  hope to help me to do that . with thanks Miss.Erin L

Comment: In 2010, you create an impersonation step the same way you create a normal step. Insert the cursor before or after an existing step, and click Impersonation Step in the ribbon. In 2013, you have to create an app step and run with elevated permissions: http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/sharepoint-tips-app-step-or-impersonation-step-sharepoint-designer-2013. Google how to do that.

Comment: Yeah i am Using Sharepoint designer 2013 and i Activated the Feature of " workflow app permissoins " but the App Steg in the ribbon didn't enabled in sp desgner

Comment: I forgot that in 2013 you can write 2010 workflows. You can use impersonation step if you create a 2010 workflow instead of 2013.

Comment: yeah i can write 2010 workflows but i have loop in workflow that run when creating an item , so i cant do loop in 2010 .

Comment: What actions do you need to run on a loop?

Comment: i have more than one loop its complex workflow

Comment: Can you have two separate workflows? One (2010) to do the impersonate create item, and another (2013) to handle your loops? I can't really help if you can't be more specific about what you're looping.

Comment: okey i wll give you an example , assume thate f the list have tow columns (No , Fact ) i want workflow run when creating an item to get factoral of any integer number in No Column ,  and when editng item i want another workflow to create an item and when creating this item i want to calculate factorial .

Comment: Okay. What I want you to try is creating 2 different workflows. In 2013, write a workflow that runs on create. Then create a 2010 workflow that runs on edit, using an impersonation step to create the new item in the list. I'll post a screenshot of what the 2010 workflow will look like in my post above.

Comment: i tried it now , workflow didnt kick of , and may cause infinite loop if it runs 
but i will try to add colums for more controlling

Comment: Who does the newly created item say it was Created By?

Comment: created by user that create workflow

Comment: That's what it should say. I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Three options;

1. Use 2010 workflows instead of 2013 if the activities you need included in 2010. This is a limitation that applies only to 2013 workflows.
2. Make Create Workflow a 2010 workflow and Change workflow a 2013 workflow and start Create workflow from within Change workflow when required.
3. I think the most elegant solution is to replicate (if practical) Create related activities within Change workflow. When you create the new item, it returns a Created variable allowing you to do pretty much anything you like on the newly created item.

Bit of a balancing act, depending what workflows do, how long they are etc.

Comment: I'm in 2010 and this limitation absolutely does apply to 2010.

Comment: Strange, I just tested this again, I am using SP Online, maybe something is different. Two workflows, one on Create, one on Change. Change has one activity to create a new item in the same list. Create just logs something to the log. Both does not use impersonation. When I make a change on one list item, a new item gets created and the new item's create workflow is executed. This scenario works when I use 2010 workflows and doesn't if I use 2013 ones.

Comment: i have to create an app step and run with elevated permissions , but also the First Workflow didn't kicked off . Why ?

Comment: What platform are you on Taher ? 2010, 2013, Online ?

Comment: sharepoint server 2013 and within sharepoint designer 2013

Comment: I Ask for any way to do that , please developers

Comment: i think it wll be work fine if creating 2010 workflows , but in my 1st workflow there is a loop , causes this i cant do loop in the workflow 2010
 i hope to give me any way to solution this problem .

Comment: Sorry when you say first workflow do you mean the one which runs on "Change" or on "Create" ?

Comment: The first workflow run when creating an item And 2nd workflow run when change

Comment: I understand, then it is not possible to use options #1 and #2 on my original post as you need a 2013 workflow for the first workflow. My recommendation is to replicate you loop (and other actions you need) in 2nd workflow. As mentioned, upon item creation you are given a Created variable which contains the ID number of the newly created item. This let's you make pretty much all changes you need.