# I'm unable to trigger a Sharepoint designer 2013 workflow automatically when an item is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, ms-flow

I used my user account (not system account) to create ms flow and sharepoint workflow using SPdesigner2013.

I'll explain the process:

> when we send an email to a shared mailbox, the msflow will create an item in stage list and associated designer workflow will create another item in "ticket list".

> Once it's created, "id" designer workflow will assign an unique id to the created item. But the id assigning workflow is not being triggered automatically but it starts automatically when an item is changed or modified. I need to start automatically when an item is created, I tried the trigger options

> I tried maximum troubleshooting as well but it didn't help, Now I got a workaround to update in sharepoint server with a sharepoint online management powershell command. I'm not sure how to use it. please help me how to initiate it and also other troubleshooting techniques as well. Help me fix this Thanks in advance.

PFB the command: stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

Comment: Would you please confirm what version of SharePoint you are using? Do you use MS Flow as well as SharePoint Designer Workflow in SharePoint server?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, SP designer (SPD) WF will be triggered when an item is created in list "Stage", right? Have you checked the SPD WF "Start Options"?
List => Workflow Settings (Ribbon)=> Workflow Settings => [Your SPD WF]

[image]

Comment: I checked that already. The workflow in stage list is perfect but the problem is with the ticket list. Once an item is created the “ID” workflow doesn’t trigger automatically. For that when I walk through, I got this command. I need a clarification on how can I implement this command.

Comment: There might be limitations that the SP2013 Designer workflow not being triggered on "Item created" when item is created by another workflow, in this case, MS Flow. You can read more on this here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174732/create-item-for-the-list-from-another-workflow?rq=1

Comment: As the 2010 sharepoint designer is about to expire, we can't implement this step, please suggest me if any . Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to trigger the id assigning workflow on item creation by the associated designer workflow.

Triggering one workflow on item creation by another is not supported, which is by design to prevent recursion. So I don’t think running the command would help.

Consider using the **[Start a List Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-start-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-within-a-sharepoint/)** action if you are using SharePoint Server. This action only supports triggering a **SharePoint 2010 workflow** within a **SharePoint 2013 workflow**.

Comment: As the Sharepoint 2010 workflow is about to expire in a month, will this step still work after Nov 1, 2020?

Comment: @ThariqAziz So I guess you are using SharePoint Online? If so then no, it won't work after the retirement.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Sharepoint site online. Is there any suggestion other than this to trigger or how can we run this below command 
stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

Comment: @ThariqAziz The stsadm commands won’t work in Online environment. I would suggest you use MS Flow to replace SharePoint Designer workflows and to trigger another flow. See the reference here: https://flow.microsoft.com/zh-cn/blog/october-updates-for-microsoft-flow/